# Read only Arabic text from file in Python

Tags: python, regex, text, utf-8, arabic

I have a text file that includes both English and Arabic words.

How can I extract into a string, only the Arabic text?

Sample file:

```
<head>
ابتداء القول الأول
</head>
<p>
وأيضاً بعض الحيوان البحرى لجى وبعضه شاطئى، وبعضه صخرى.
</p>
```

And the desired output is:

```
only_arabic = "ابتداء القول الأول وأيضاً بعض الحيوان البحرى لجى وبعضه شاطئى، وبعضه صخرى"
```

I couldn't find regex that helps me with this issue. What am I missing?

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3750257)

Comment: If the english text is just html tags you can exclude the html tags by regex like 's/<[^>]*>//g' (sed command in linux )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406247/how-to-remove-english-text-from-arabic-string-in-python

Comment: You can use `unicodedata` module (it is a module in standard library). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html, and last example: iterate codepoint, and keep Arabic (and possibly punctuations, spaces, numbers, and other symbols within Arabic text).